# Pairing of values in a Pythons list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder with 300 txt files. lets say the .txt names are a, b, c, d etc.
I need to compare each pair with a python script. I need to compare a-b, a-c,a-d, b-c, b-d. I do not want to have a-a and also i don't want to have both a-b and b-a.
My guess was something like

```
for x in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']:
     for y in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']:
          if x != y:
            print(x , y)
```

but i am getting both a-b and b-a etc. If i scale it at the 300 file names i will get a few thousands duplicate outputs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are talking about `combinations`, and there is a method to do this in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.combinations): `for x, y in itertools.combinations('abcd', 2):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [combinations](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2012/11/how-do-use-itertools-in-python-to-build-permutation-or-combination/) from itertools:

```
from itertools import combinations

files = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
filesCombine = combinations(files, 2) # [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
for f1, f2 in filesCombine:
    # compare f1 with f2
```

The second argument is the length of each combination, in this case 2

Comment: thank you so much, thats exactly what i need!

Comment: You're welcome @EfthimisAvgeris , you can accept the answer if it helped you, below the arrows up/down on the left side of the answer (: .